# Why Sp_lock doesn't show RID type?

Tags: sql-server

When I execute sp_lock on my db I see some rows with RID which defines which record is locked:
[image]

If I execute sp_lock on another server and another db with another user I don't get RID:
[image]

Why? Could it be a grant problem on the user?

Answer (score 2):

The table in your db is a heap.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes

"When a table is stored as a heap, individual rows are identified by reference to a row identifier (RID) consisting of the file number, data page number, and slot on the page. The row id is a small and efficient structure."

Your dml statement needs to lock the corresponding row(s) and each row is identified by RID.

On the other server, with another table and another user,  the table is a clustered one.
Each row is identified by the "value" of the clustered index.
Your dml statement needs to lock the corresponding row(s) and each row is identified by KEY (value of the index).

Comment: thank you very much. The problem was exactly the problem was precisely the presence of a clustered index